# IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException, returns more than one elements

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data JPA repository in which I need to obtain the entries by name and item fields.

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, 

    {
            public Item findById(String id);
            public List<Item> findByNameAndItem(String name, 
            String item, Pageable pageables);
    }
```

Item:

```
class Item{

    private String id;

    private String idTrans;

----
```

I call the metod likethis:

```
return itemRepository.findByNameAndItem
            (name,item, new PageRequest(0, 10));
```

Error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: result
>   returns more than one elements; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than
>   one elements] with root cau

Comment: have you take a look at this [post](http://www.javabrahman.com/j2ee/jpa/no-result-exception/). Suppose `List<Item>` does not have a promise of a unique index, so JPA doesn't like mapping to it.

Comment: CrudRepository is defined on AssessedItemLink where as findByNameAndItem returns List<Item>. I suppose that has to be List<AssesseditemLink> or a valid jpa projection. Can you post the code for AssessedItemLink and Item classes as well?

Comment: I updated the post, was a copy paste mistake, is Item all over.

Comment: It should be fine that way. But maybe the naming is a problem here: your Entity is named `Item` and it also has a field `item` which is a String. In your repo method `findByNameAndItem` the camel case writing indicates that you want to filter by given String `name` and `item`. Can you check if it stays the same when changing the attribute's name?